How can I repair an outlet which won't accept plugs?
I am not able to plug in stuff into my outlet anymore. It seems like every time I try to plug something in, I'm hitting some springs. I think I moved the inside of the outlet by forcing things in.

Latest update: The face came off.


Latest update, I got the face off. I applied so much pressure, I lost the springs and the screws attaching the face .

Think of it like a drinking glass. If it breaks, it's not smart to glue it back together to use.

@Traveler, don't put unsupported opinions and ill-advised suggestions in comments. Post an answer so it can be evaluated or move on.

Just replace it with a new one.  Receptacles and switches are not worth repairing.  When they do not work or start acting differently.
They are usually only a couple of dollars and easy to replace with a new receptacle.
Turn off the breaker, check that there is no power there, take pictures of how the wires are connected.

Take pics of both sides of the old receptacle, noting whether the tab that connects the side screws is in place or broken off.

Thanks I will do that when Im back in the country.

First thought: Are you plugging in right side up? Even when not grounded, mist modern plugs and outlets are polarized, with one blade slightly wider than the other. The plug will only go in one way.
Addendum: You say the fit is now very loose. OK, that is clearly a damaged socket. Replace it.

Yeah, it was working for the past year but I must have moved it somehow? After playing around with it for the past hour now, im able to plug in stuff but its very loose, they just drop out of the socket. or I have to keep applying pressure on it to keep the electricity flowing through

If it's very loose, that's a damaged socket. Replace it.
